# Custom sized Flux DataBuffer within WebSocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-webflux

I'm trying to make a live video stream where on the backend chunks are received and stored into a DataBuffer which then is continuously writen to a File. But instead of a bigger getting DataBuffer and file, I rather want a DataBuffer which is limited in its size and (hopefully) works like FIFO, so that if new chunks are pushed into the DataBuffer, older chunks are pushed out.

What I tried is to create a DataBuffer with the `DataBufferFactory` and `allocateBuffer()`, but this always gives me type missmatch errors because I have the `Flux<DataBuffer> videoDataFlux` which contains the chunk data on the one hand, and a `<DataBufferFactory>` on the other hand, which somehow can't be combined.

So, whats the way to go?
**What is working so far:**

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {

  String filename = "strm";

  Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\
                                                   Tomcat 9.0\\webapps\\stream\\videos");

  Flux<DataBuffer> videoDataFlux = webSocketSession.receive()
                                  .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayload);

  try{          
    Path file = Files.createTempFile(path, filename, ".webm"); 
    AsynchronousFileChannel channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(file, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);     

    return (DataBufferUtils.write(videoDataFlux, channel, 0)                            
           .then()
           .doOnNext(s -> { 
             if((!videoDataFlux.equals(null)) && (!webSocketSession.equals(null))){  
             DataBufferUtils.write(videoDataFlux, channel, 0).subscribe();
             }
           }));

          } catch(IOException e){  
         }

  return null;
}
```